# Remote Machine running JVM needs to publish Git Commit Hash, deployment done with Gradle. NOT ANDROID

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

Every answer I have found related to this subject has been for android specifically.

What I have been able to do so far is upon build - in the build.gradle file get the Git Commit Hash and then put it in either the Manifest Files or under a "Resources" Folder within the bundles.

```
task create_gitCommit << {

    if (project.getName().equals("com.freewire.mobi.unitconfigurationimpl")) {

        String s = null;
        String temp = null;
        try {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process proc = rt.exec("git rev-parse --short HEAD");
            System.out.print("The following the output of the pwd command ")
            System.out.println(rt.exec("pwd"))
            System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"))
            System.out.println(GroovySystem.version)

            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

            // read the output from the command
            System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
            if ((temp = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                s = temp;
                System.out.println(s);
                File file = new File("com.freewire.mobi.unitconfigurationimpl/src/main/resources/gitCommitHash.txt") {}
                file.createNewFile();
                file.write s
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION CAUGHT, something is not going correct");
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is, once the code is running on the virtual machine, I have tried to access the file path and then publish the variable. But I don't think the file structure is the same on the remote machine as on my local.

```
private String getGitTextFilePath() throws Exception {         
Resources.toString(Resources.getResource(fileContents), 
Charsets.UTF_8);
    ClassLoader classloader = 
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream is = 
classloader.getResourceAsStream("gitCommitHash.txt");
    InputStreamReader streamReader = new 
InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    BufferedReader reader = new 
BufferedReader(streamReader);
    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    System.out.println(is.toString());
    LOG.info("GIT TEXT file path " + 
is.toString());
    return is.toString();
}



public String getGitCommitHash() throws Exception{

    String everything = "Fake";
    String path = getGitTextFilePath();
    LOG.info("Working Directory = " +
            System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    try{
        LOG.info("Inside Try 1");
        LOG.info(fileContents);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
FileReader(path));
        LOG.info("Inside Try 2");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();
        LOG.info("Inside Try 3");

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        everything = sb.toString();
        br.close();
        LOG.info("Inside the try: " + everything);
        return everything;

    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Something went wrong with trying 
to read the Git Commit Hash File :,)");
    }
    return everything;
```

Option 1 - is to figure out how to find out what that file structure is and harvest the GitCommitHash I have placed in the specified folders.

Option 2 - is there a way to get the Git Commit Hash remotely? It's easy on my machine as the folder I'm in when making the build is connected to the repo. Is it possible to get the Commit Hash from the remote machine within the Java code itself?.

tl;dr - in the build.gradle I can put Git Commit Hash into a file in the correct bundle I want. Either under a resources folder, or in Manifest file. This works. 
However, once the code is deployed on the remote server https://www.eurotech.com/en/products/iot/multi-service-iot-edge-gateways/reliagate-20-25, I don't know how to access that file. How do I get the file structure? Or can I somehow access Git from the remote server using Java to get the Git Commit Hash.

Comment: The git plugin in Jenkins creates environment variables. One of them : GIT_COMMIT. You can use it to write into your file. If you need short - just use substring... Depending on your Jenkins config - it's possible that there is no git on build node, or there is no git metadata in your working dir...

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but gradle also allows you create a manifest "in the right place".  https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/java/archives/Manifest.html

Comment: You don't say what goes wrong when you try to read the file. Any output and error log would be helpful! I also agree with @dagget that you are better off using a plugin to generate the file and/or manifest.